# What is the difference between element.classList.contains() and element.matches()

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript you can check whether an element has a specific class by using the following options:

**Option 1**

element.classList.contains('someClass');

**Option 2**

This option also allows to check for multiple classes where as option 1 does not (would require separate check for each class)

element.matches('.someClass');

**Question**

Which option should be used when and are the any other differences between them other than mentioned? Which one is less expensive?

Comment: One is more generic than the other. "*Which one is less expensive?*" [Benchmark them!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) Although it's very likely it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`element.matches` allows for a much more flexible test.

If you *only* need to check if an element has or doesn't have one particular class, feel free to use `contains`. But if you want to do additional checking based on what CSS selectors the element can match, `.matches` allows for a much more concise method of achieving that goal. For example:

```
element.matches('a.someClass.foo')
```

will return `true` if `element` is an anchor element, which has a `someClass` class, and also has a `foo` class.

```
element.matches('.someClass[data-num="3"]:hover')
```

will return `true` if `element` has a `someClass` class, has a `data-num` attribute of 3, and is being hovered.

Expense doesn't matter - the performance cost is next to nothing regardless.

Answer (score 2):

> The **matches()** method checks to see if the Element would be selected by the provided **selectorString** -- in other words -- checks if the element "is" the selector. Source: [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Matches is not testing only classes but whole selector (any attribute of element). For example you can use it for data attributes:

```
element.matches('[data-anything="value"]')
```

`classlist.contains()` is only for classes.

---

**Which one is less expensive?**

Personally I think it doesn't matter but in theory `contains()` should be less expensive because it's targeting only one specific attribute.